# DownloadURL failing due to proxy authentication

Tags: servicestack

I am setting up facebook authentication with servicestack and have been getting the return type #f=Unknown, I've tracked it down to coming from the authentication block:

```
try
{
    var contents = accessTokenUrl.DownloadUrl();
    var authInfo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(contents);
    tokens.AccessTokenSecret = authInfo["access_token"];
    session.IsAuthenticated = true;
    authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
    OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo.ToDictionary());

    //Haz access!
    return authService.Redirect(session.ReferrerUrl.AddHashParam("s", "1"));
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    var statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
    if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        return authService.Redirect(session.ReferrerUrl.AddHashParam("f", "AccessTokenFailed"));
     }
 }

//Shouldn't get here
return authService.Redirect(session.ReferrerUrl.AddHashParam("f", "Unknown"));
```

The reason for it dropping through is the catch checks the response status code.  In my scenario I am receiving 407 Proxy Authentication Required.

I've tracked it down further to the line:

```
var contents = accessTokenUrl.DownloadUrl();
```

Can anybody help with how I put in place the required proxy authentication?

For info, my app is running in a windows environment, it is run as an windows authenticated user so has permission access the proxy server, I just need to tell the code to use this - or any - credentials.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [setting the default proxy for .NET applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) by setting the `<defaultProxy/>` in your Web.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        usesystemdefaults="true"
        proxyaddress="http://192.168.1.10:3128"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
      <bypasslist
        <add address="[a-z]+\.contoso\.com" />
      </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The servers configuration has been updated so that they don't need to go through a proxy and that has fixed it for me.